# Need help to recreate a metal material with multiple colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This is the reference I would like to recreate:
[image: Reference image with the metal]

Would be great if someone had an idea how to do it.

Comment: Which metal do you want?

Comment: The one on the side, that looks a bit scratched and glossy in multiple colors, similar to gasoline.

Comment: The copper sheeting? That can be done moderately easily. Use glossy, and a scratch texture as a mix factor for a shinier copper material.

Comment: Do you think the colors come solely from the reflection? Is it possible to create a color variety in the material?

Comment: I think what appears to be multiple colors is the light from a window reflecting off of it. It really doesn't have a gasoline sheen.

Comment: Okay thank you all very much for your answers!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise do you mind answering this? I tried but I'm just not good enough at nodes :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried something, more complex than I expected. The mesh is not flat, a bit deformed (large area proportional edited vertices, very low distance)
[image]

Basic [scratch texture](http://www.cgtextures.com/texview.php?id=6850) form CGTextures.com, not reworked, not tilabled.
Lights are a pain, could use a ref to get something decent. It looks like something is throwing light (ground reflection?) on the seats shadows.
I think the Blue/green colors are due to the use of acid on copper, could be textured.

Comment: @David good to know, thx (it was a screenshot but no difference i guess)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an image texture with an emit shader and/or an environment map:

[image]

The bluish part comes from an image texture wired to an emission shader, the white stripe was added by the anisotropic shader.

[image]

The surface is displaced by a noise texture here with scale at 29 (exaggerated for demonstration):

[image]

Another try:
[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/34605)